# Simulating jobs scheduler as an API

Tags: c++, system-design

I have to design a system that adds jobs for workers and checks on them. There can be multiple workers, so multiple tasks can be completed simultaneously, and if the number of jobs is more than workers then they're added to a queue.

My job is to design some code that will add jobs and check on jobs and some separate code will make calls to my functions,

so I need to mainly design 3 functions,

```
init(3)                            //initializes no of workers
add_job(timestamp, burst_time);    //adds a job and returns number of jobs in the system
jobs_active(timestamp);            //returns No of jobs in the system
```

Burst Time is a concept used in OS and scheduling, it's serving the same purpose here so I used it here.
Burst time refers to time required to complete the job.

`jobs_active` function returns same thing as `add_job` without adding a new job

You can assume only one operation can be performed at a time.

What I'm not sure about is how I should simulate time in this question.

for eg, in the following run, each function call would give different answer based on the timestamp

```
init(2)                       //initializes time = 0, set no of workers as 2
add_job(1, 4);   // returns 1 //Add a job at time=1, burst time = 4, job would get finished at time=5 (1+4) 
jobs_active(3);  // returns 1 //checks jobs in system at time = 3, currently 1 
jobs_active(5);  // returns 0 //At time=5 job added at 1 ends here
add_job(6, 3);   // returns 1 //Add a job at time=6, burst time = 3, job would get finished at time=9 (6+3)
add_job(7, 3);   // returns 2 //Add a job at time=7, burst time = 3, job would get finished at time=10 (7+3)
jobs_active(8);  // returns 2 //At time=8, both previous jobs are active
jobs_active(9);  // returns 1 //At time=9, job added at 6 is finished
jobs_active(10); // returns 0 //At time=10 job added at 7 ends here
```

In above example, when the job is added at time=1, with burst time = 4. it will end at time = 5 (1+4),

Comment: Adding a timestamp variable seems utterly insufficient, you need to choose a container for the jobs. Issue is that meanings of your function arguments and return values (IOW what?) look under-specified. What is burst time? Same things said in different but equally dim wordings: 1) "returns number of active jobs" When active? 2) "returns No of jobs currently active" When is that "currently"? Some kind of unspecified mysterious sync function?

Comment: @ÖöTiib, hi I added more explanation to the example, added meaning to burst time.

and removed my approach even I knew it was very inefficient didn't seem worth while to keep it there and add discussion around it

Comment: It feels that it is unclear to yourself what the software should do. You replaced "active jobs" with even more hazy "jobs in the system". You do not describe what happens with add_job when  job can not be scheduled to that timestamp and what number of jobs it will return. Time seems to be represented as integer value in there so it does not make sense to me what you mean by "simulate time".